# Does Flutter allows us to push Live updates?

Tags: android, google-play, flutter

Does flutter allows us to push live updates without updating the app through play store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a roundabout way, yes. If you are using firebase in your app then [this plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_remote_config) will let you remotely configure your app via firebase. This is the best option currently

Comment: Great! Thanks @Conner

Comment: If that was what you were looking for please mark this correct, it'll help me out

Comment: Okay did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. [It may come in the future](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14330).

Comment: Thanks! But you can use @Conner 's answer as well. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_remote_config

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but you can use this package to send an update alert.

https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31909094)